# Combinations in one row with Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, merge

the data I have looks something like this.

```
Trade -- Strategy -- -- Maturity

Swap -- OMASW28  -- 10 -- 4/5/2028

Bond -- OMASW28 -- 20 -- 4/5/2028

Bond -- OMASW28 -- 30 -- 4/5/2028
```

The main goal is to find out all the possible combinations and their cumulative Totals, for instance, I want the final table to look like this.

```
Trade -- Strategy -- Totals -- Maturity -- Trade -- Strategy -- Totals -- Trade -- Strategy -- Totals

Swap -- OMASW28  -- 10 -- 4/5/2028 -- Bond -- OMASW28 -- 20 -- 4/5/2028 -- 
Bond -- OMASW28 -- 30 -- 4/5/2028
```

And at the end of each row, a field with the total Total, which would be 10+20+30 = 60 in this case.

I have gotten upto here, but this seems too lengthy and complicated.

```
Trade_x Strategy    Nominal_x   Total_x Maturity_x  Trade_y Nominal_y   Total_y Maturity_y
Swap    OMASW28 -20000000   10  4/5/2028    Swap    -20000000   10  4/5/2028
Swap    OMASW28 -20000000   10  4/5/2028    Bond    20000000    20  4/5/2028
Swap    OMASW28 -20000000   10  4/5/2028    Bond    1000    30  4/5/2028
Bond    OMASW28 20000000    20  4/5/2028    Swap    -20000000   10  4/5/2028
Bond    OMASW28 20000000    20  4/5/2028    Bond    20000000    20  4/5/2028
Bond    OMASW28 20000000    20  4/5/2028    Bond    1000    30  4/5/2028
Bond    OMASW28 1000    30  4/5/2028    Swap    -20000000   10  4/5/2028
Bond    OMASW28 1000    30  4/5/2028    Bond    20000000    20  4/5/2028
Bond    OMASW28 1000    30  4/5/2028    Bond    1000    30  4/5/2028
```

Which is basically the following code,

```
a = pd.read_csv('files/input.csv')

b = pd.read_csv('files/input.csv')

merged = a.merge(b, on='Strategy')
```

This merges twice, I need it thrice for this particular case, if I had 10 rows with 4 columns each, I want the final table to be 40 columns wide!
Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean that this is twice?

Comment: I mean it merges it once, with all the other rows. So, now I have the comparisons with all the possible two rows. I want the merge so be I can have all the possible combinations of all the three rows, initially present!